# I try to implement the SQLite3 library to work with SQLite through CocoaPods and it gives me a bug that I don't understand

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, swift4

I do not understand the reason for this error because it does not specify much. I would like to create a SQLite database using the SQLite3 library using CocoaPods but when running the application after solving some bugs I skip this. I'm lostCould you help me?

**This is my Podfile file code:**

```
project 'TFG.xcodeproj'

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'TFG' do

  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for TFG
  #pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Functions'
  pod 'FirebaseUI'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.11.5'


  target 'TFGTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'TFGUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

This is the one that gives me "`Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT`" jumps in the fourth line of the following code:

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
    0x101bd2598 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
    0x101bd259c <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x101bd25a0 <+8>:  b.lo   0x101bd25b8               ; <+32>
    0x101bd25a4 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x101bd25a8 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x101bd25ac <+20>: bl     0x101bd1934               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x101bd25b0 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x101bd25b4 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x101bd25b8 <+32>: ret
```

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint, repro the issue, then post the result. This will give you a better stack trace, and hopefully better indicate the source of the crash.

Comment: To add an exception breakpoint, go to the breakpoints tab on the left side of Xcode (or press Cmd + 8), then go to the bottom left, tap + and select "Exception Breakpoint..." and leave the default options.